# Interpretation of line 7 and 8 of TFW file

Tags: geotiff-tiff, world-file

I found the following TFW file

```
0.05     # x-scale; each pixel is 0.05 meters wide
0        # rotation about x-axis
0        # rotation about y-axis
-0.05    # y-scale; each pixel has a height of 0.05 meter
-749.975 # horizontal coordinate of the center of the top left pixel
649.975  # vertical coordinate of the center of the top left pixel
30000    # ? 
26000    # ?
```

I know what the values in the first 6 lines represent.

However, what do the additional two lines represent?

Comment: I'm not sure there should be a line 7 or 8 - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file Where did you get the file from?

Comment: Just a guess, number of pixels in x and y?

Comment: @BERA I think you're right. If we divide 649.975 / 0.05 = 12,999.50. If we multiply this by 2 and add 1 we get 26000 / the 8th line. Any idea what's the idea behind this?

Answer (score 3):

These are non-standard lines in a `TFW` file, but they seem to be consistenly used in the [website you mentioned](https://www.pgatour.com/competition/2022/bmw-championship/tourcast.html#/hole-view?round=4&hole=1) in your comment.

For example, besides `course.tfw`, on the same page there is [terrain01.tfw](https://tourcastdata.pgatour.com/shotlinkgraphics/2022/r/028/901/ARL/3D_Assets/terrain/terrain01.tfw)

which reads:

```
-0.049997
0.000669
0.000669
0.049997
205.177746
-71.561698
4147
9872
```

However, both `course.jpg` and `terrain01.jpg` are square images:

```
$ identify terrain01.jpg 
terrain01.jpg JPEG 4096x4096 4096x4096+0+0 8-bit sRGB 3.84914MiB 0.000u 0:00.000
$ identify course.jpg 
course.jpg JPEG 2048x2048 2048x2048+0+0 8-bit sRGB 1.07962MiB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Therefore I would not bother: this is just a site-specific implementation.
(I reamin curious, however, about the meaning and use of those lines)

Comment: If we divide 649.975 / 0.05 = 12,999.50. If we multiply this by 2 and add 1 we get 26000 / the 8th line. Any idea what's the idea behind this or what could be the purpose of it?

Comment: Good observation. also: 30 000/750 = 26 000/650 = 40, however that doesn't work for the other file (`course.tfw`). By the way: 649.975 is actually 650 - 0.5/2 because it is the coordinate to the _center_ of the top-left pixels